# Windows 10 Explorer: How to show full path in titlebar, but only currently opened folder in taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar, path, title-bar

Please read my question in full.

In the file explorer in Windows 10, [I know you can set the text](https://www.top-password.com/blog/display-full-path-in-title-bar-of-windows-10-file-explorer/) displayed in its titlebar to either the current folder or the full path. This setting [applies also to the text displayed in the taskbar](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3430-display-full-path-title-bar-file-explorer-windows-10-a.html).

Is there a way to split this into two separate settings? I mean, I want the full path to be displayed in the titlebar of the window, where there's a lot of available space, but when I minimize it, or even just move to another window, I only want the name of the current folder in the taskbar, which is limited in space anyway. It's more reasonable and useful in my opinion.

Thank you!

Comment: i don't think its is possible through build in commands because when you set the full path display it can't be reversed when you change the windows.

Comment: Why not you enable both registry that you've mentioned?

Comment: @Biswapriyo How exactly? There is only one registry value - a boolean indicator for "display full path". It does not apply separately for the titlebar and the taskbar.